# Make a user account on Windows 10 a full admin

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've always hated this about Windows, it's ridiculous admin antics. If I'm an admin user I want to edit things like my host file without needing to hack around.

Previously on 8.1 I found something for the console that changed my user account to a full admin account and removed the horrible restrictions on the standard admin accounts.

Is there anything I can do on Windows 10 to make my admin account a fully blown admin account free from restrictions?

Comment: Uhm ... being admin does **not** mean you *have* full access everywhere. Not by a long shot. It just means that you can *gain* access everywhere. And if you want to edit a file that isn't otherwise writable more conveniently I suggest `icacls` or `cacls`. Btw: it might help if you were more explicit about what mysterious "something" you found for 8.1 that allegedly did what you wanted. Because your question isn't very clear and seems to be based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: As a side-note, not even being LocalSystem means you would *have* access everywhere, but yet again you can *gain* access if you wanted to. It used to be the case at some point in the evolution of NT-based systems that LocalSystem meant having full access *everywhere*, but that has improved in recent years/Windows versions.

Comment: As far as I know the only account that can do things "as Administrator" without having to "Run as Administrator" is the built-in "Administrator" account.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press “Win+R” keys, and this will open a Run prompt.

2. At the run prompt, type `lusrmgr.msc` and then click OK.

3. Now Local User & Groups Panel will open. Click on Users in the left column to display a list of all user accounts currently in your Windows installation.

4. Right-click on Administrator account listed in the center column and select properties.

5. In the Properties box, type a name for your Super Administrator account and make sure that the field "Password never expires" is enabled (checked) and "Account is disabled"  disabled (unchecked).

6. Click on OK to create the new account.

7. To set the password, right-click on Administrator account again and select "Set Password".

Now when you restart your computer or sign out of your account you will have an additional account displayed for the Administrator.

---

Why do you want to create a super administrator account?

1. You don’t want to be ‘annoyed’ by UAC.
2. This ‘Built-In’ administrator account has elevated privileges. This means that you can run CMD with an un restricted access to the command line.
3. You need to carry out some serious troubleshooting.
4. You have locked out your main account by accident and you want a back door entry.

Comment: But this creates another account. Can I make my current admin account have full access? This is essentially enabling the 'Hidden Administrator Account'

Comment: This is not the same as 'Run as administrator', and is not answering question.

Comment: I get an error: http://prntscr.com/m5pcnu

Comment: Irrelevant and does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

At the run prompt, type lusrmgr.msc and then click OK

Find your user name, go to its properties, make sure you are in the administrator group and remove yourself from the user group, restart your pc

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the computer asking for admin credentials before allowing you to do certain things? in which case this should help:
add yourself to the admin group and turn off the UAC.

Turning off the UAC:
    Open User Account Control Settings by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type uac, and then click Change User Account Control settings.
    Do one of the following: To turn off UAC, move the slider to the Never notify position, and then click OK.

This will turn off all prompts asking for Elevated Rights.

Comment: the fact that he does not know how to disable this, means probably he shouldn't. Those who know how to disable it, usually are knowledgeable enough to leave it in place.

Comment: I have UAC fully disabled and still can't edit the hosts file without opening the Editor explicitly "as Administrator". Therefore i don't think OP is talking about UAC.

Comment: I have the UAC on and it doesn't even ask me. No run as admin required to edit the hosts

Comment: @kazaamjt: UAC can be "on" at different levels of "nuisance". No contradiction here.

Comment: -1: You should never turn off UAC on a workstation, especially not on Windows 10. Moving the slider to the lowest position does not turn-off UAC, not in Windows 10 and not in Windows 8.x

Answer (score -1):

To edit the host file, first, place a shortcut of your Notepad on the desktop. Right click on the notepad and choose RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR. Go to Windows/System32/drivers/etc and open the host file, do whatever you please with it and save. The key is to open NOTEPAD as administrator.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I think you posted this answer on the wrong question, as it's asking how to make a user account full admin.

Answer (score -1):

To gain absolute control of your computer and be done with all the restrictions Microsoft imposes on you do the following. Run Explorer as administrator, go to Windows/system32 and find lusrmgr.exe, right click and choose to create a shortcut, Windows will tell you it cannot create a shortcut in the directory and ask you whether you want it on your desktop. Say YES. Once on your desktop right click on it and choose run as administrator. 
Using lusrmgr.exe delete all users and groups leaving yourself as the Administrator. Give that administrator all the privileges (Full control etc.)Retain your password and make sure it never expires. You have now made yourself a Super Administrator with absolute control of your Windows 10 computer, you can open any file regardless of whether it is hidden or read-only, whether it is a system file etc. and you can do all the mischief you want. Before this can take effect you must restart your computer - cross your fingers or byte your nails praying you did everything right. :)

Comment: That is probably the worst answer I've seen on any of these sites yet...
**Never** do such a thing, these users are here for a reason, plus deleting them is not even helpful to the question asked here.
**Do not** delete them, as it is likely to leave you with a malfunctionning (if not broken) Windows.